# Random variables on a triangle

Tags: probability

The pair of random variables $(X,Y)$ is distributed uniformly on the triangle with vertices (0,0), (1,2) and (2,0). What is the conditional density $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ and what for distribution does $X|Y=y$ have?

I know that the formula for conditional  density is $f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$, but I don't know how to continue from there.

Comment: $f_{XY}(x,y)$ is constant, subject to $(x,y)$ actually being in the triangle.  You could try to find $f_{Y}(y)$ first.

Comment: @Henry but what is that constant?

Comment: $1$ / Area of triangle

Comment: @Henry So then $f_Y(y)$ is $1/2(2-y)$?

Comment: It might be clearer to say something like $f_Y(y)=\dfrac{2-y}{2} I[0\le y\le 2]$ where I is an indicator function

Comment: @Henry could you maybe show me a solution for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is only meaningful for $0 \le y \lt 2$.

Given that, to be in the triangle, you must have $x \ge \dfrac{y}{2}$ and $x \le 2- \dfrac{y}{2}$.

So given $Y=y$, X is conditionally uniformly distributed on the interval $\left[\frac{y}{2},2- \dfrac{y}{2}\right]$ and has a conditional density on that interval of $\frac{1}{2-y}$.

Your approach give the same answer.  The joint distribution is uniform inside the triangle and has density $\frac12$ there, so overall has density $f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac12 I\left[0\le x \le 2, 0 \le y \le 2, y \le 2x, y \le 4-2x\right]$. 
So $f_Y(y)=\frac{2-y}{2} I[0\le y\le 2]$.

This gives $f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)} =\frac{\frac12 I\left[0\le x \le 2, 0 \le y \le 2, y \le 2x, y \le 4-2x\right]}{\frac{2-y}{2} I[0\le y\le 2]} = \frac{1}{2-y} I\left[0 \le y \le 2,\frac{y}{2} \le x \le 2- \dfrac{y}{2}\right]$, at least when $0 \le y \lt 2$.